# Why \n is coming while converting path to in String using swift 3

Tags: json, swift, bundle, decode, encode

I am fetching path from Bundle and converting it in string

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Questions", ofType: "json") {
    let str1 = try String.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), encoding: .utf8)
}.
```

I am getting string but don't know why I am getting "\n" in the end. There is no extra line in son file.

After that I am trying to decode it but because of "\n" I am not able to do.

```
let decodeData = Data(base64Encoded: str1)
```

Comment: How about adding `.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespaceSet)`?

Comment: But If suppose any other response will come in that space is given than ?

Comment: What is the contents of the resource file? Base64-decoding a *JSON* file makes no sense.

Comment: Encrypted data is there in JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Questions", ofType: "json") {
let str1 = try String.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), encoding: .utf8)
}
```

The path in the above code is already a string. Why are you encoding a string into another string? What is the purpose of that?